# Unable to ingest JSON data with MemSQL PIPELINE INTO PROCEDURE

Tags: apache-kafka, singlestore

```
I am facing issue while ingesting a JSON data via PIPELINE to a table using Store Procedure.

I see NULL values are getting inserted in the table.
```

Stored Procedure SQL:

```
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ops.process_users(GENERIC_BATCH query(GENERIC_JSON json)) AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ops.USER(USER_ID,USERNAME)
        SELECT GENERIC_JSON::USER_ID, GENERIC_JSON::USERNAME
        FROM GENERIC_BATCH;
    END //
    DELIMITER ;
```

MemSQL Pipeline Command used:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PIPELINE ops.tweet_pipeline_with_sp AS LOAD DATA KAFKA ‘<KAFKA_SERVER_IP>:9092/user-topic’

    INTO PROCEDURE ops.process_users FORMAT JSON ;
```

JSON Data Pushed to Kafka topic:  {“USER_ID”:“111”,“USERNAME”:“Test_User”}

```
Table DDL Statement: CREATE TABLE ops.USER (USER_ID INTEGER, USERNAME VARCHAR(255));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting help in the MemSQL Forums at https://www.memsql.com/forum/t/unable-to-ingest-json-data-with-pipeline-into-procedure/1702/3  In particular it looks like a difference of `::` (which yields JSON) and `::$` (which converts to SQL types).

Answer (score 0):

Got solution from MemSQL forum!

Below are the Pipeline and Stored Procedure scripts that worked for me,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PIPELINE OPS.TEST_PIPELINE_WITH_SP 
AS LOAD DATA KAFKA '<KAFKA_SERVER_IP>/TEST-TOPIC'
INTO PROCEDURE OPS.PROCESS_USERS(GENERIC_JSON <- %) FORMAT JSON ;


DELIMITER //
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ops.process_users(GENERIC_BATCH query(GENERIC_JSON json)) AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ops.USER(USER_ID,USERNAME)
SELECT GENERIC_JSON::USER_ID, json_extract_string(GENERIC_JSON,'USERNAME')
FROM GENERIC_BATCH;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```